# Without changing sql mode=only_full_group_by mode how can I execute group by in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I am trying get month wise sum of amount from transactions table. I have written below cakephp function to get my desire output.

```
public function getLastSixMOnthsExpenses($since_date, $t_type)
{
           $query = $this->find()->select([
                 'month' => $this->find()->func()->monthname([
                   'created' => 'identifier'
                ]),
               'amount' => $this->find()->func()->sum('Transactions.amount')
            ])
            ->where([
               'Transactions.created >='=>  $since_date->modify('6 months ago')->startOfMonth(),
               'Transactions.created <='=>  $since_date->endOfMonth(),
               'Transactions.transaction_type '=>$t_type
            ])
            ->group(['month'])
            ->order(['Transactions.created'=>'ASC'])
           ;
    
           return $query;
 }
```

I am getting below error

```
Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'kjoumaa_kamaljoumaa.Transactions.created' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

Without change sql mode , How can I run group by here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order on an aggregate instead.

Since you group by the month, all `created` fields in those groups will be of one and the same month, eg all `created` fields in one group will point to either an earlier or a later date than the fields of another group, so you could simply pick either the min or the max value out of a group:

```php
->orderAsc(function (
    \Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression $exp,
    \Cake\ORM\Query $query
) {
    return $query->func()->min(
        $query->identifier('Transactions.created')
    );
})
```

```sql
ORDER BY MIN(Transactions.created) ASC
```

Also if you would select the month as a number instead of as a name, you could order on that field.

Comment: Should I replace it on order ? after replace on order I got error 
Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ASC' at line 1

Comment: @NiloyRony Check the full SQL that is being generated.